# Installing a plugin for a Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to add a plugin to my project and this is when I get this error:

```
PS D:\My Projects\***\trunk\dev> cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin.git
Fetching plugin from "https://github.com/phonegap-build/GAPlugin.git"...

C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Fetching plugin failed: Error: "git" command line tool is not installed: make sure it is accessible on your PATH.
    at C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\plugin.js:90:41
    at _rejected (C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

The "`D:\My Projects\***\trunk\dev`" contents has been created by "`cordova create . <project-name>`" and "`cordova platform add android`" commands.
I've installed Git from http://msysgit.github.io/ and it's available in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`.

What do I miss?

Comment: did you add C:\Program Files (x86)\Git to the path?

Comment: Can you add `-d` to the command, like: `cordova plugin add -d https://...` and see if it gives you any more information? Are you connected to the internet and not behind a firewall? Is `git` on your path?

Comment: Thanks, I've add Git to the Path as you said and now it works :)